# stuck on proof $\{\inf X_n <x\}=\cup_{n\in N} {\{X_n<x}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

We have  $X_n:\Omega\rightarrow R$ a sequence of random variables (measurables functions).
I have to show that $\{\inf X_n <x\}=\cup_{n\in N} {\{X_n<x}\}$ Where the infimum is taken over $n$ and $x \in R $.

I have written $\{\inf X_n <x\}=\{\omega \in \Omega:\inf X_n<x$} but don't know how to continue from here. I know that there is a relation between the $\exists$ quantiver and the $\cup$, but I don't see how to use this on the infimum.

Answer (score 2):

If $\omega \in \{X_n < x\}$ for some $n$, then $(\inf X_n(\omega)) \le X_n(\omega) < x$ so $\omega \in \{\inf X_n < x\}$.

Conversely if $X_n(\omega) \ge x$ for all $n$, then $\inf X_n(\omega) \ge x$.